# Use Lstm for classifying problem

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, classification, recurrent-neural-network

i have a dataset of 10000 event with 16 feature, and a vector of dimension 10000 that represent the label of each event; for what i understand is a classification problem but it's required to use a Lstm. How it's possible to use a RNN for a classification that doesn't involve a temporal series? And how can i implement this in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Classification can totally be done using LSTM. While this is a [duplicate of another question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-possible-to-use-recurrent-nn-lstm-for-classification?rq=1), I can provide an example article that demonstrates how this can be done [through code](https://www.bobbywlindsey.com/2021/01/09/how-to-detect-passive-and-active-voice-in-your-writing-using-an-lstm/).

Comment: thanks for your answer! i've alredy see the other question but our dataframe are different, and my problem is the input shape: how can i fed my model with my dataset n x m and my label vector?